Save an image of an area by it's index
General Question: Is there a way to capture a raw image, so no overlay or gizmo, of an area within Blender only by its index?
I would need a script that writes the pixels of the area to an image within Blender without using any modal operators.
The following link already addressed the question, however it utilizes a modal operator that I don't really need. In my case, the script should be executed once and then an image of the currently active viewport should be created and if it already exists it should be overwritten. Copy framebuffer of 3D View into custom frame buffer.
The viewport render option won't work as it does not function in cycles and rendered view mode.
But how could I achieve something like this? Any help is really appreciated and responses in the form of code lines are very welcome as well!
Thank you for your time and effort!

"The following link already addressed ..." - What following link?
